# when should we use an anonymous class to implement a listener and when we may prefer a different implementation

Tags: java, swing

We have 4 ways to implement listener:
- An inner class
- An anonymous class
- A class inside a method
- Make the container of the GUI component a listener
My question is: Which ones are the most commonly used? Why? And when should we use an anonymous class to implement a listener and when we may prefer a different implementation? Why?

Comment: You can have a listener in a separate class as well.

Comment: Your classification is rather strange since your *ways* are not mutually exclusive.  Very often listeners are implemented as anonymous inner classes.

Comment: that is 4 ways i'm already know. so I listed but if it seem like strange i would take out 4 ways i knew and left the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has written an article [General Information about Writing Event Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/generalrules.html) that gave a detailed explanation of which one of the four ways should you use to implement your event listeners.

As for *"...when should we use an anonymous class to implement a listener"*, the simplest answer would be when you need to extend two or more classes, say, `extends SomeParentClass, MouseAdapter` Since this is not allowed in Java, what you can do instead is to use an anonymous class to extend your `MouseAdapter` and have your enclosing class just `extends SomeParentClass`.

Comment: Anonymous classes are just syntactic sugar and can't do anything that named classes can't do, such as extend multiple superclasses.

Comment: Still not great--you never *need* to extend the adapter classes, and that's why the contract is on an interface--but improved.